# Вывод alert в другое окно

Tags: php, javascript

Есть форма отправки запроса:

```
$("#form1").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "forms_ajax/mail1.php",
        data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        $(this).find("input").val("");
        alert("Спасибо за заявку! Скоро мы с вами свяжемся.");
        $("#form").trigger("reset");
    });
    return false;
});
```

Выдаёт такое сообщение :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно как-то инфу из alert вывести в отдельный блок или просто над формой?

Comment: Добавляете в форме пустой блок и вместо alert пишите $('селектор пустого блока').html('Текст ошибки'), при клике на сабмит чистите этот блок.

Answer (score 1):

Если "вывести в отдельный блок или просто над формой", то над формой можно сделать пустой div (с заданным классом, например .response-div), а по success писать в него нужный текст, например:

```
$("#form1").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "forms_ajax/mail1.php",
        data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        $(this).find("input").val("");
        $(this).find('.response-div').text('Спасибо за заявку! Скоро мы с вами свяжемся.');
        $("#form").trigger("reset");
    });
    return false;
});
```

А вообще в таких случаях лучше явно пользователю показать, что запрос отработал. Модальное окно например вывести с сообщением.

Comment: Только не забудьте очищать div прои вводе новых данных! )

Comment: .text эту куда нужно прописать в html код где сама форма?
я создал перед формой div <div class="response-div"></div>

Comment: .text() запишет текст в див. Также можно использовать функцию .html()

Comment: <div class="response-div"></div> при данном коде нужно вставить внутри формы, например перед <input>

Answer (score 0):

Можно.

```
$('селектор_в_который_нужно_вставить_текст_из_алерта')
     .text('Текст из алерта или любой другой, который вы хотите вставить')
```

Comment: если вам не сложно не могли бы пример написать я просто новичок еще не могу понять(